# Invalid MIME Message AWS SES is rejecting it due to invalid MIME message

Tags: validation, email, mime, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an attachment through AWS Simple Email Service, and i can get it to send a raw email WITHOUT ATTACHMENTS, however when i try it with attachments it always fails. Have i constructed my MIME message correctly?

Ok so here is the MIME that sends correctly:

```
From: test@example.com
To: test@example.com
Subject: Test Email
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello, This is a test email.
```

When I attach the attachment is fails to send:

```
From: test@example.com
To: test@example.com
Subject: Test Email
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello, This is a test email.

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/txt; name="test.txt"
Content-Description: test.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgYXR0YWNobWVudC4=

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
```

Is there anything obviously wrong?

I contruct the call by base64 encoding the whole message and adding it to the end of this URL:

```
Action=SendRawEmail&Destinations.member.1=test%40example.com&RawMessage.Data={base64 encoded MIME Message}
```

**ANSWER:**

There were two issues with the MIME file. First

- The trailing boundery shouldnt be there, as it is obviously looking for another aspect of the MIME message, eg another attachment.
- The Content-Type which is defined as "text/txt" should actually be "text/plain"

Thus meaning with those two alterations you get this MIME message which works:

```
From: test@example.com
To: test@example.com
Subject: Test Email
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello, This is a test email.

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/plain; name="test.txt"
Content-Description: test.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgYXR0YWNobWVudC4=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues with the MIME file. First

- The trailing boundery shouldnt be there, as it is obviously looking for another aspect of the MIME message, eg another attachment.
- The Content-Type which is defined as "text/txt" should actually be "text/plain"

Thus meaning with those two alterations you get this MIME message which works:

```
From: test@example.com
To: test@example.com
Subject: Test Email
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello, This is a test email.

--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
Content-Type: text/plain; name="test.txt"
Content-Description: test.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgYXR0YWNobWVudC4=
```